# WPF When clicking on the different Treeviewitem the related part of the text in TextBlock gets highlighted

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock, ivalueconverter, xamlreader

I have a Treeview and a Textblock and both of them populated with the data from the backend by using MVVM. The TextBlock contains the formatted hex string (it looks like this:

0000:  ad  be  e6  00  25  00  00  00  9e  7b  3b  04  40  01  db  07
0016:  03  04  0a  00  00  39  e0  00  00  05  1d  27  31  81  00  2d
0032:  00  01  12  d3  ab  4f   00  01  01  c4  00  00  00  03  8c  09

Each Tree node object (viewmodel) has a startByte (where should the highlight start) and ByteLength (the length of bytes to be highlighted) properties. What I need to achieve is when clicking on a tree node, the related hex string (part of the whole hex string in the Textblock) needs to be highlighted based on the two properties mentioned above. If you have used the Wireshark, you'll know what I'm talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try doing it using a TextBox with `IsReadonly="True"`, plus a style\control template to remove any frames around the text. For preventing user input, I'd make it `IsHitTestVisible="False"`.

Then, I'd use the selection of text box to make the highlight (in code).

This has limitations, the main one is that you'd have only one 'span' of text selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the TextRange and its ApplyPropertyValue method to set the TextElement.BackgroundProperty to solve my problem. If anyone needs help with the similar questions, I think I can provide some suggetions.